# 3D mapping using Octomap with Turtlebot

Tags: mapping, turtlebot, octomap, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
(ROS - Electric; Ubuntu 11.04)
This is in continuation to the [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/29017/octomap-with-turtlebot/).
I am trying to build a 3D occupancy map using the octomap_server with kinect sensor on top of the turtlebot.
Following are the launch files i ran

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
```

Turtlebot navigation package launches the /turtlebot_bringup/kinect.launch which has the throttling and fake laser for 2D mapping and localization purposes.

Now i try to run the

```
roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping.launch
```

I have modified the cloud_in and frame_id as given below

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">
        <param name="resolution" value="0.05" />
        
        <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
        <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="/map" />
        
        <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
        <param name="max_sensor_range" value="3.0" />
        
        <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points" />
    
    </node>
</launch>
```

But the occupied_cells_vis_array topic gets the marker_array in the camera_depth_frame which is orthogonal to the actual kinect frame where the fake laser is being published.
Hence i changed the frame using

```
<param name="frame_id" type="string" value="/camera_depth_optical_frame" />
```

to get it to the frame of actual kinect.
But this leads to the Map being build to be orthogonal to the kinect frame. The resulting image is attached [image: here].

I am sure that the gmapping is able to convert the camera_depth_optical_frame of the kinect to camera_depth_frame internally and creates the Map correctly.
But when octomap_server is run this Map is again reframed. Please help me to resolve this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36887/3d-mapping-using-octomap-with-turtlebot/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, My colleagues were successful in finding the solution.

Fixed frame in rviz as: /odom

Target frame as: /camera_depth_frame

In the octomap_server/octomap_mapping.launch file with frame_id as /odom.
We are able to get the 3D mapping done.

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabian Saccilotto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2806/fabian-saccilotto/) on 2013-01-17**:
I am trying the same. But actually I can produce a quite good map with gmapping but when I connect the pointcloud to octomap as you do it, the octomap has a lot of artefacts from the situations were the robot's position inside the map is not correct. Did you have this problem too?

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2013-01-19**:
Yes, i mean the fusing of the maps are not so great as the 3D occupancy grids are not getting updated with respect to their probabilities I guess. It took a lot of effort to get a good map with Kinect sensor. I think either you need a good odometry or a good sensor to get a good map at the least.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-01-20**:
Try adding a Hokuyo laser to your robot for 2D. It will give you much better pose estimates in amcl or gmapping.

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-07-10**:
hi, guys I also get octomap working. As pointed out by above, the 3D map is not updated; the image (with wrong location) stays in the map and will never be erased. I am wondering how do you guys solve such problems?

**Comment by [emteasee](https://answers.ros.org/users/5426/emteasee/) on 2013-07-16**:
Hi I cannot get the octomap working using the proposed solution above. There are no issues with Kinect connectivity. The camera is working as required, I just cannot see the visualisation of the pointcloud as shown in the example above? Could anyone help

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2014-02-04**:
I was able to produce the 3d map, but the density of point cloud is very small. The points are very widely spaced. What might be the reason. How do I change this parameter?? Can you help?